# Scala : UTC to Local time based on ZoneId

Tags: scala, time, locale, jodatime, java-time

I am trying to convert UTC timestamp to local time based on Country Code (2 digit) . Can some one tell me which time function I should use here? Couldn't find any proper examples.

```
import org.joda.time._ 
val start = "2016-10-24T03:00:00Z"
val utc = new DateTime(start)
println("UTC = " + utc)


val result1 = utc.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("US/Central")) 
val result2 = utc.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Gaza"))
```

But not working. Can some tell me what I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: So how do you intend to handle countries with multiple time zones (such as the US)?

Comment: I have a map for countries to get ZoneId

Comment: Right, it's not enough to say it's "not working".  We can figure this out by the fact that you're here in the first place.  You need to tell us what you expect to happen, why you expect it to happen, and what actually is happening.  Then we will at least take your question seriously.

Comment: @JoeC I am planning to convert the UTC time to local time based on Zone eg ."US/Central" I am trying this in Zeppelin where I don't see any error just 0.

Comment: I just ran your code myself and it works just fine.

Comment: Can you post the result you get ? I still don't see any result in Zeppelin

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. Do you speak about new `java.time`-package as your title suggests? Or do you speak about Joda-Time as your code example suggests?